# Floating Navigation Height Removed From Page

Tags: css

Hi I recently made my site navigation "sticky" for : [https://shiftins.com](https://www.shiftins.com). The only problem is the height of the navigation has been removed from the page and looks like it became a separate layer that "floats" over the page. It ends up hiding some of the top parts of my page content. I tried adding margins and padding to various containers but there are too many different ones sitewide. Is there a solution that will make my site honor the height of the sticky navigation site wide?

Here is the code I used:

```
.site-header {
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
background: #0074E5;
background: #0c5798;
height: 60px;
box-shadow:inset 0 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.site-header .wrap {
padding: 0;
}

.site-header {
position: fixed;
width:100%;
height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `top:0;` on your fixed header. Then add the margin to a global div like `site-container` like this this:

```
.site-container{
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.site-header {
position: fixed;
width:100%;
height: 60px;
top:0;
}
```

Comment: When I do that, it creates a white space at the top of my banner/hero images. Is there a code that makes the site honor the headers height without a margin?

Comment: Search for #top-wrap  and remove margin-top:50px and margin-top:60px. You have it twice.

Comment: It works great on all the pages except my home page. It looks like I'm using margin site wide and then another on the homepage specifically. Can you help me identify the extra margin on the home page?

Thanks by the way you're making this super easy to understand for a non-coder!

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I would give you feed back but I need 15 reputation. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad you did. You don't lose reputation on upvoting and accepting answer. In fact you get more - try it.

Comment: It won't let me because I just created an account

"Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: Oh, my bad. I get it now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

float element always remove the parent height so you have to use overflow:hidden: on parent element or apply **clearfix** hack/class

see this [Css trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)